# Int with no value (set int to no value)

Tags: swift, swift2, integer, int

I want to create an Int that has no value (an already existent variable). If I do this;

```
number = Int()
```

then it still has the value `0`. I want nothing, a nonexistent value.

Comment: The only way is an optional `Int?`

Comment: You need Optionals: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330

Comment: `var number: Int?`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Every type can actually be set to an empty value aka `nil`!

To create a variable that can be set to `nil`, you need to write the type name explicitly with a `?` or `!` (I'll talk about the difference later) at the end.

For example, if you want an `Int` that can be set to `nil`, declare a variable with the type name:

```
var myInt: Int
```

and then you add a `?`:

```
var myInt: Int?
```

Then, you can set `myInt` to `nil`, or whatever values you want:

```
myInt = nil
myInt = 0
```

This type-name-with-? notation is known as "Optional Types" in Swift.

Not only can you use optionals in variables and constants, you can also use it in method/function signatures:

```
func myUselessFunc(value: Int?) -> Int? {
    return value
}
```

Okay, so what's the difference between `!` and `?`?

`!` acts like reference types in Java and C#. And `?` is like a safer version of `!`.

Let's say there's an optional `Int` called `myInt`. You want to access its `description`.

If `myInt` were declared as `let myInt: Int?`,

```
myInt?.description
```

If `myInt` were declared as `let myInt: Int!`

```
myInt.description
```

Notice that with the question mark, you need to add a question mark at the end every time you need to access property/method of `myInt`. This is called "Unwrapping an optional type".

A type with the `!` suffix is called an "Implicitly Unwrapped Optional Type". When working with these types, you don't need to unwrap it. However, if `myInt` is `nil`, there will be an error! This doesn't happen with `?` types because the whole expression will just return `nil` if `myInt` is `nil`.

That's just something I think you should note when you work with optionals the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You need an Optional `Int`. By putting a question '?' mark you initialize that varaible by nil.

```
var number: Int?
```

Refer this link for more details 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html